# How do I choose where to output in a file?

Tags: linux, tcl, csh, tcsh

I have a file like this:

```
file1:
a aa 
b bb
c cc
```

```
file 2: 
d dd ddd
e ee eee
```

I want to output the contents of file2 to file1, at the line with pattern I choose, like before line with a, after line with b like this:

```
file 1:
d dd ddd
a aa 
b bb
e ee eee
c cc
```

I only know how to use puts in tcl or >> with echo in csh, but they only output in last line.

Comment: Why don't you create a 3rd file? Read F1 and F2, then put in F3 as you want.

Comment: I guess I could do that too, but isn't it harder to do so? I can't just add 
`d dd ddd`, then add 
`a aa
b bb`
then add 
`e ee eee`
and then: `c cc`, I think it would be faster to find the pattern and add the line

Comment: It should be easier I think. eg. In your case, how are you choosing where you want to insert lines from F2 in between lines of F1? Use the same logic, read through both the files and create a 3rd file.

Comment: I'm trying to set a Runtime for my script (file 1, and a lot of other files), which will have many command and proc. So I'm trying to find a way to insert something like `date >>runtime` between the command/proc that I choose, and in multiple script too. And to do that I need to know how to insert at which line I choose, so I can implement in my script to use in the future

Comment: Look into `ed`? For example, `printf "%s\n" '/a/-1 r file2' w | ed -s file1` will insert the *entire* contents of file2 before the first line of file1 with an a in it and save the changed file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seek` to change where the channel points within the file, but that works using *byte* offsets into the file (the correspondence with characters is complex and depends on the encoding and what the contents really are). It also does not alter the byte offsets of any data that you don't explicitly rewrite; while that's often absolutely fine for binary data, it's a problem with textual data as that usually changes the length of lines when rewritten. (This is inherent in how both POSIX and Windows view files; lots of languages work the same way as a consequence.)

So… for text, you're actually better off loading all the text into memory, performing the edit there, and then writing the whole file from scratch, as in-place text editing is possible but so immensely awkward that almost nobody does it that way.

---

The two procedures below are simple stanzas for converting between files and lists of lines of text.

```
proc linesOfFile {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    try {
        return [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}

proc writeLinesToFile {lines filename} {
    set f [open $filename w]
    try {
        puts $f [join $lines "\n"]
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}

# Read the data
set linesOf1 [linesOfFile file1.txt]
set linesOf2 [linesOfFile file2.txt]

# Do the edits; indices are zero-based
set linesOf1 [linsert $linesOf1 0 [lindex $linesOf2 0]]
set linesOf1 [linsert $linesOf1 3 [lindex $linesOf2 1]]

# Write back
writeLinesToFile $linesOf1 file1.txt
```

I've no idea how to merge the files other than poking the lines in like that; there's many options, but you've kept that info back.

Comment: Thks for the answer, I got the general idea.